# How to solve "Insufficient Permission" for userUsageReport with Google API?

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to write a Python script that will check if a user account has got two-step verification enabled.

As a starting point, I'm using the quickstart script provided on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/python. I've followed the instructions and the sample code works as expected.

I then add the following line after the example code:

```
results = service.userUsageReport().get(userKey='john.doe@example.com', date='2016-08-02', parameters='accounts:is_2sv_enrolled').execute()
```

but I get "Insufficient Permission" returned.

Just to make it clear, I do replace "john.doe@example.com" with an email address that is valid for my organisation :).

I've double-checked the credentials used and, indeed, if I use the web-based API Explorer with the same account being used to run the script, it works.

I don't understand why the call to activities().list() is working but userUsageReport().get() isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this.

userUsageReport requires the usage scope to be added, specifically:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly

Since the quickstart only reference the audit scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly

that is why I was getting the error.

Comment: How did you modify your code to include the readonly scope?

Comment: @FaultyJuggler if you look at the link in the question, the sample code has a line that says "SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']". You can define multiple scopes here, comma-separated. So, in addition to the "audit.readonly" scope, I had to add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly"

Sorry - the comment editor is hiding the "https://" prefixes. Please bear that in mind when reading my reply.